# Banco de dados CodeFirst Entity Framework, 1-0..1, 1-N

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Eu possuo 3 tabelas e preciso relacionar as mesmas via código (Code First)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso. Já possuo os seguinte códigos das tabelas:

**TbHistoricoAnalogico**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("HistoricoAnalogico")]
public class HistoricoAnalogico {

    public HistoricoAnalogico(){

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data e hora do valor
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DataHora{
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Valor da Digital
    /// </summary>
    public float Valor{
        get;
        set;
    }

}//end HistoricoAnalogico
```

**TbTendenciaAnalogico**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Autonav.ComunicacaoBanco.Autonav.Entidades
{
    [Table("TendenciaAnalogico")]
    public class TendenciaAnalogico : Base
    {
        [Required]
        public long TempoDeVidaEmDias
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public int TempoDeColeta
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int tagId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TbTagAnalogico

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  TagAnalogico.cs
//  Implementation of the Class TagAnalogico
//  Generated by Enterprise Architect
//  Created on:      02-set-2016 16:17:48
//  Original author: Silvano
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

/// <summary>
/// Classe responsável por gerar e mapear as entidades da tabela de tag Analogico
/// no banco de dados.
/// </summary>
/// 
[Table("TagAnalogico")]
public class TagAnalogico : Tag {

    //public Tendencia Tendencia;
    //public AlarmeAnalogico alarmeAnalogico;
    //public Dispositivo dispositivo;
    //public Tag tag;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indica qual e o valor maximo que a tag pode variar.
    /// </summary>
    public int BandaMorta{
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Forma que o valor da tag vai ser exibido na tela
    /// </summary>
    public string FormatoExibicao{
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maior valor que a tag pode receber. Utilizado para mostrar um alerta ou
    /// mensagem
    /// </summary>
    public String MaiorValor{
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Menor valor que a tag pode receber. Utilizado para mostrar um alerta ou
    /// mensagem
    /// </summary>
    public String MenorValor{
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unidade de engenharia
    /// </summary>
    public string UnidadeDeEngenharia{
        get;
        set;
    }

}//end TagAnalogico
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, `Tendencia` possui N `HistoricoAnalogico` e cada `TagAnalogico` pode ter 0 ou 1 `Tendencia`. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Tendencia pode ter nenhuma ou muitos HistoricoAnalogico, cada TagAnalogico pode ter 1 tendencia.

Comment: Sim, mas qual registro vem primeiro? `TagAnalogico` ou `Tendencia`?

Comment: TagAnalogico....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comecemos por `TagAnalogico`:

```
[Table("TagAnalogico")]
public class TagAnalogico : Tag 
{
    // Você precisa identificar ou aqui ou na classe ancestral a chave.
    [Key]
    public int TagAnalogicoId { get; set; }

    //public Tendencia Tendencia;
    //public AlarmeAnalogico alarmeAnalogico;
    //public Dispositivo dispositivo;
    //public Tag tag;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indica qual e o valor maximo que a tag pode variar.
    /// </summary>
    public int BandaMorta { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Forma que o valor da tag vai ser exibido na tela
    /// </summary>
    public string FormatoExibicao { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maior valor que a tag pode receber. Utilizado para mostrar um alerta ou
    /// mensagem
    /// </summary>
    public String MaiorValor { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Menor valor que a tag pode receber. Utilizado para mostrar um alerta ou
    /// mensagem
    /// </summary>
    public String MenorValor { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unidade de engenharia
    /// </summary>
    public string UnidadeDeEngenharia { get; set; }

    // Aqui são declaradas as propriedades de navegação.
    // É por elas que o Entity Framework é capaz de deduzir as relações entre Models.
    // Elas PRECISAM ser `virtual`, ou o Entity Framework não irá entender a anotação. 
    public virtual TendenciaAnalogico TendenciaAnalogico { get; set; }

}//end TagAnalogico
```

Como `Tendencia` é 0..1 com `TagAnalogico`, ela precisa ter, por definição, a mesma chave de `TagAnalogico`. Ou seja, a chave primária de `Tendencia` também é chave estrangeira para `TagAnalogico`:

```
[Table("TendenciaAnalogico")]
public class TendenciaAnalogico : Base
{
    // Veja que aqui anoto que a chave é primária e estrangeira ao mesmo tempo.
    // Veja mais abaixo que "TagAnalogico" é uma propriedade virtual, 
    // indicando ao Entity Framework a relação 1-0..1. 
    [Key, ForeignKey("TagAnalogico")]
    public int TendenciaAnalogicoId { get; set; }

    // Procure colocar todas as chaves, primárias ou estrangeiras, no começo da declaração da classe.
    public int tagId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long TempoDeVidaEmDias { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TempoDeColeta { get; set; }

    // Aqui a propriedade de navegação que associa TagAnalogico com Tendencia.
    public virtual TagAnalogico TagAnalogico { get; set; }
    // Aqui a propriedade que relaciona 1 Tendencia com N HistoricoAnalogico
    public virtual ICollection<HistoricoAnalogico> Historicos { get; set; }
}
```

Repare que a configuração de 1 para N é feita através de uma anotação `public virtual ICollection<>` em `Tendencia`. Da mesma forma, precisamos colocar a relação inversa em `HistoricoAnalogico` através de dois elementos:

1. O campo da chave estrangeira;
2. A propriedade de navegação da entidade relacionada.

Ou seja:

```
[Table("HistoricoAnalogico")]
public class HistoricoAnalogico 
{
    [Key]
    public int HistoricoAnalogicoId { get; set; }
    // 1. O campo da chave estrangeira;
    public int TendenciaId { get; set; }

    // Não precisa isto
    //public HistoricoAnalogico(){

    // }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data e hora do valor
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Valor da Digital
    /// </summary>
    public float Valor { get; set; }

    // 2. A propriedade de navegação da entidade relacionada.
    public virtual TendenciaAnalogico TendenciaAnalogico { get; set; }
}//end HistoricoAnalogico
```

Comment: No TagAnalogico é assim mesmo? public virtual Tendencia Tendencia ou faltou o get; set; ?

Comment: Erro meu mesmo. Desculpe. Já editei.

Comment: ta me retornando o erro na hora que vou fazer o migrations: Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'TagAnalogico' and 'Autonav.ComunicacaoBanco.Autonav.Entidades.TendenciaAnalogico'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: Ah, sim. Você deve ter `Tendencia` e `TendenciaAnalogico` no mesmo projeto. Vou editar novamente pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: @JeffersonSouza Veja a modificação que fiz em `TagAnalogico`.